# Strange behavior of html

Tags: html, django

I don't know why but when i have html i this order:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <div id="header" style="width: 1020px; height: 50px; vertical-align: sub; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; background-color: white;">    
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <span><a class="header_urls"  href="{{ URL }}/accounts/profile/">Profile</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <span style="float: left; color: blue; vertical-align: sub"><a class="header_urls" href="{{ URL }}/blog/">Blog</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <span style="float: left; color: blue; vertical-align: sub"><a class="header_urls" href="{{ URL }}/gallery/newest/1">Something</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

        {% endif %}
    </div>
</html>
```

Outpu is: Blog, Somthing, Profile.
and in chrome code spectrator code is in this order, it display this things in other order. Why could it be?

Comment: Please show the final generated HTML, not the source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the items are in different order you probably have `float: right` on them

Comment: Right. I found that it is not because i have `float: right` on them, but i haven't `float: left` on first of them. Thank You.